# In need of hardware to connect to a mysql server over gprs

Tags: arduino, remote

Has anyone come across any hardware that we can put out on a remote site (in a field) that uses a sim card to create a gprs connection to a mysql database server.

I've looked at the arduino but that protection we'd need to put around it to "industrialise" it is very costly,

Comment: What sort of "protection" do you need?

Comment: Cooling, electrical protection, loop isolation. (i'm no electronics engineer, but a web dev) so i'm just passing on requests from the engineers

Comment: Keep in mind that the arduino is actually a very simple circuit. All it *really* does is power the AVR and break out the pins to standard connectors. You can make a custom PCB with a similar AVR chip that suits your physical needs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want something like [this](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10138). It has a sim card slot and an antenna connector. It supports SMS text messages, GSM/GPRS, TCP/IP etc. To get started I'd get one of these and the corresponding evaluation board, transitioning to a custom PCB with a similar form-factor for the product. Then you can put everything into a neat square enclosure and off you go.